# How can you detect on runtime if your sql-server 2005 instance is a 32 or 64 bit instance?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2005

How can you detect if your sql-server 2005 instance is a 32 or 64 bit instance from C# code? If you know some documentation on this issue, please let me know..
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use [SERVERPROPERTY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174396.aspx) ( propertyname )

With property name Edition.

64-bit versions of the Database Engine append (64-bit) to the version.

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY ( 'Edition' )
```

For me on my x64 machine returns the following string value:
Enterprise Edition (64-bit)

You could also check the env variable PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE to see what the machine itself is running as.

Comment: Is this listed also on the registry or can be concluded from a file version? I need a way to do this not assuming I have a valid connection.

Comment: updated answer with PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE note. I'm not 100% sure if you can install an x86 SQL on an x64 though.  But I don't think you can.